# Quantum mechanics interpretations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-interpretations, theory-of-everything

Let's assume that the existance of the graviton is proved theoretically or it is detected by the LHC and there is found a way for Pilot Wave Theory for it to account to special relativity via the constructive quantum field theory. Is there a way for any interpretation to be proven theoretically(because they all make the same experimental predictions) correct(Copenhagen,many worlds, pilot wave (my personal favourite)etc. (thus creating a Theory Of Everything)?

Comment: A theory of everything would explain all phenomena with one theory. It would not be a bunch of contradicting theories put together.

Comment: These theories added together do explain all phenomena, don't they?

Comment: No, not only do they not explain All phenomena but some of them may contradict each other.

Comment: 1 They can be connected (quantum gravity and constructive qft) 2They do explain everything

Comment: No there are still way too many unanswered questions. We don’t even have a good model for the atom. As is we have incorporated words like dark matter, dark energy or even wave particle duality to account for what we don’t understand. We need more physical models to explain things.

Comment: I think there arre unanswered question not because the theories don't explain all phenomena, it's just due to our ignorance(just my opinion). But back to my original question:"Is there a way for any quantum mechanics interpretation to be proven theoretically correct?"

Comment: "Fundamental" particles are assumed. Atom would have been fundamental particle few centuries ago. But as you keep breaking particle into more and more smaller particles, eventually you find nothing. So, "Theory of Everything" will not be different from "Theory of Nothing". Because "nothing" is "something" that makes "everything".

Comment: Can you answer the main question:"Is there a way for any quantum mechanics interpretation to be proven theoretically correct?"

Comment: This question contains a lot of random, unrelated parts. Existence of the graviton has nothing to do with interpretations of quantum mechanics. Picking an interpretation of quantum mechanics is neither necessary nor sufficient for creating a theory of everything. Proving the existence of the graviton is neither necessary nor sufficient for creating a theory of everything. (And BTW the LHC cannot detect gravitons, even in principle.)

Comment: *"Is there a way for any interpretation to be proven theoretically (because they all make the same experimental predictions) correct?"* Theories which produce the same experimental predictions are either both correct or both incorrect. If two theories make the same predictions, the only remaining issue of merit is which one is simpler or more suitable for particular types of calculations or better for various aspects of intuition.

Comment: Ultimately there should be an actual physical model that explains your theory. Four instance there were many highly respected theories that proved the earth was the center of the universe. Many of those theories were mathematical. It turns out none of them were right and we actually do have a physical model now to describe not only our solar system but galaxies and clusters too. Models can always be built on and fine-tuned as we go along but you got to start somewhere.

Comment: @BenCrowell LHC cannot detect gravitons — I thought people were looking for missing energy corresponding to gravitons in LHC predictions (and have found nothing, obviously).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way for any interpretation to be proven theoretically

No. The word interpretation and the concept of "proof" are incompatible. One can prove a theorem in an axiomatic mathematical theory, and write "quod erat demonstrandum." Physics theories use axiomatic mathematics and impose extra axioms called "postulates", "laws" "principles" to choose a subset of the mathematical solutions that fit the data; modeling the data is the objective.

You are enumerating different physics models which use different mathematics to fit the data , and you are assuming they all fit the data  well, with equal accuracy within errors . If this ever becomes true, there is no way to chose between the mathematics, and call that "real". The only comparison tool would be simplicity of calculations.

[Here is an example](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~az/lectures/ia/lect2.pdf) of using complete sets of functions to mathematically model a photograph.

[image: expand]

The photograph is the data which is modeled by the mathematics in a series expansion using fourier transforms and summed on the right. The physical theoretical model.

One  *interpretation* is given by these α β γ ...  that build up the photograph, based on fourier transforms.

Suppose another set of complete functions did the same mathematical job as well as the  α β γ  above, call them a b c d ..... Do you see a way of proving one as correct/real and the other as false/unreal  as long as the exact photo is reproduced?

In physics it is the data that always check a mathematical  theory. If two theories explain equally well the same data, the only choice is simplicity of calculations, not "correct" because they are both correct in describing the objective, the data.

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently any experimental prediction that distinguishes the various interpretations. That is, they all predict the same thing, but employ different concepts to do so.

They differ mainly in how they suggest further developments can be made, and in how well they integrate with the concepts employed in other physical theories and other scientific fields.

For example, Pilot Wave Theory reasserts causality, whereas the Copenhagen interpretation rejects causality. Physicists have tended to have a pet interpretation to which they personally subscribe, but differences in preference (and the reasons for adopting one interpretation over another) essentially come down to matters of taste rather than scientific proof or robust reasoning.

Comment: So the question is:Is there a way for any interpretation to be proven theoretically correct?

Comment: @AnglelKld, as I say there is no current experimental difference, but they could still be subject to a test of *internal consistentcy* - that is, whether the concepts employed integrate with themselves, with the rest of science, and with everyday life. I would say the general Bohmian approach is probably the one that integrates best, and there have been experiments carried out which support it (https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4356). But it is the least popular interpretation amongst physicists.